# Quero saber como limitar a casa decimal em c++ usando std

Tags: c++

Então estou fazendo um programa simples e queria saber como faço pra limitar a casa decimal na entrada, colocando o cin e pegando somente 1 casas, por exemplo digito 2,6534 e o programa só pegue o 2,6. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

double a, b;

cin>>a>>b;

cout<<(a+b)/2<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Coloque um código minimo, completo ou verificável, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para definir a quantidade de casas decimais a serem escritas deve utilizar [`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) e [`fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/):

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
```

O numero passado em `setprecision` indica a quantidade de casas decimais a serem escritas. Tudo o que é escrito dai para baixo segue os decimais previamente definidos:

```
double num = 2.6534;
cout << num; // 2.7
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/7zWEyJ)

Se quiser escrever mais números é só fazer `cout` diretamente pois a precisão já foi definida.
É relevante mencionar que precisa adicionalmente de incluir o header `<iomanip>`:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

Note também que o resultado não é `2,6` como tinha mencionado e sim `2,7` pois funciona como se fosse arredondado. Se quiser truncar terá que o fazer manualmente à custa de funções existentes em `<cmath>` tal como a função [`floor`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/).

Só mais uma recomendação, evite usar `using namespace std`. Eu mantive para estar de acordo com a sua pergunta, no entanto isso pode-lhe causar problemas com colisões de nomes entre outras coisas.

Seguindo esta recomendação, portanto sem `using namespace std` ficaria assim:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);
double num = 2.6534;
std::cout << num;
```

[Veja também esta versão no Ideone](https://ideone.com/WZONjG)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e pela recomendação, então no caso do using namespace std; você recomendar usar o padrão std::cout?

Comment: @Prometheus Sim é mesmo o mais recomendado. Pode ver [esta pergunta sobre esse tema no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Naturalmente para pequenos exemplos educativos acabará por não fazer diferença, mas em coisas mais sérias não é recomendado.

Comment: Obrigado, estava criando praticas péssimas, vou começar a usar o std::cout, grato pela recomendação!!! No caso do seu código sem o using namespace std; ficaria assim, std::cout<<fixed<<precision(1); ?

Comment: @Prometheus Ficaria assim `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);`. Editei a resposta para contemplar também essa versão.